How to generate BootROM with alternative boot code
I want to generate a BootROM that contains different software instead of using the default one. I've generated the bootrom.img in upper directory where rocket-chip repo is cloned. Then I've created a TLROM instance inside ExampleRocketSystem by calling a convenience function bootROM.create() that I've implemented which takes the updated version of BootROMParams that points to correct content file. But I'm receiving an error that diplomacy complains about 0 inward 0 outward ports of a TL node which is instantiated inside TLROM. What's the best way to get RTL of an alternative BootROM version along with the default one in single build?
